# How to change recup_dir file permission?

Tags: permissions, file-format

I lost some files on an external hard drive. When I used a recovery process on the files they read only.  Only root has permission to change the read only settings.  How do I change those recup_dir files so that they can be copied or cut?

Answer (score 2):

Change the ownership of the folders:

```
sudo chown -R  $USER: recup_dir*
```

You will be asked to type your sudo password.

- `sudo`: run a command as super user (root)
- `chown`: change ownership
- `-R`: for a folder and everything below that folder
- `$USER:`: to current user and his primary group (note the `:`)
- `recup_dir*`: all subfolders from current directory beginning with .recup_dir

Comment: `sudo chown -R  $USER:` is enough, it's going to assign user primary group by default ;)

Comment: that is why I love SE. While helping others I'm learning new stuff too ;-) Thanks @Ravexina